# Histogram with percentage bins in Python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, gnuplot, histogram

I need to create a histogram with percentage bins from a 2D set of data, like this (this is basically a set of reports from various devices, each line is a device reporting its status for a given hour):

```
# hour # parameter (in percents)
00     10
00     20
00     30
01     40
01     50
...
```

so that there would be a stacked histogram summary of the devices' reports binned by hour and percentile, just like the gnuplot example below, with bins representing the percentiles the reports fall into (say 0 < r < 10%, 10% < r < 20% and so on).

[image]

Right now I've only thought about creating a 2D array and feeding it all to gnuplot like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import sys

data = np.loadtxt('mac-quality.csv')
out = [ [ 0 for k in xrange(10) ] for i in (xrange(24) ) ]

for i in data:
    hour = i[0].astype(int)
    quality = i[1].astype(int)
    for bin in xrange(10):
        pct = bin * 10
        if quality > pct and quality < (pct + 10):
            print('Data: %s, H: %s Percentile: %s:') % (i, hour, pct)
            out[hour][bin] += 1
# print(out)
```

What would be the correct way of generating these histograms from within python?

Comment: Could you provide an exceprt of the `cvs` data?

Answer (score 1):

This uses exactly your python code, but extends it with some [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html) library code, which is commonly used for plotting in python. This generally replaces gnuplot in python.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('mac-quality.csv')
out = [ [ 0 for k in xrange(10) ] for i in (xrange(24) ) ]

# Number of bins you have
nBins = 10

for i in data:
    hour = i[0].astype(int)
    quality = i[1].astype(int)
    for bin in xrange(10):
        pct = bin * 10
        if quality > pct and quality < (pct + 10):
            print('Data: %s, H: %s Percentile: %s:') % (i, hour, pct)
            out[hour][bin] += 1


plt.hist(data, nBins, normed=1, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
plt.title('Some Title')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not exactly that, it's plotting the data binned by percentile, while I'd like a stacked percentile histogram binned over hour (hour being the X axis and percentiles being bins inside the stacked histogram bars). But thanks, it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the ask - but you could do:

```
data = [ ... ]
bins = 10 or [manual bins here]
bin_numbers = np.digitize(data, bins=bins).flatten()
answer = np.bincount(bin_numbers) / len(bin_numbers)
```